# Obtaining the fonts distributed with texlive without installing texlive

Tags: fonts, texlive, installing, tlmgr, installing-fonts

I would like to install all the fonts (from CTAN?) that texlive would install under TEXMF/fonts to an arbitrary directory on an Unix system without running the texlive installer. It would also be great to keep them up to date.

Comment: If you use a normal texlive install and the option to omit `doc` then `fonts` is almost all the space, it would be simpler to install it and just ignore the rest, tl2022 updated yesterday has

Comment: `$ du -hs *
2.4M    asymptote
25M     bibtex
24K     chktex
2.5M    context
3.5G    doc
16K     dvipdfmx
7.0M    dvips
2.7G    fonts
56K     hbf2gf
4.7M    ls-R
182K    makeindex
270K    metafont
15M     metapost
17K     mft
1.8M    omega
248K    pbibtex
1.0K    psutils
130M    scripts
414M    source
538M    tex
22M     tex4ht
26K     texconfig
20K     texdoc
44K     texdoctk
9.0K    ttf2pk
279K    web2c
32K     xdvi
3.4M    xindy`

Comment: I'm actually just interested in the OpenType fonts. But thought that downloading just them would be trivial once I know how to get all of them. Therefore, I asked the question in a more general way.